# How would you read a file using node.js which is json?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have a json file that's formatted like this:

```
{
    "156914300718415872": { "client" : "Uber" }
}
```

Everytime someone says .verify for discord, it will put the snowflake id via that number with whatever role they have like Uber.

How would you get the id and the client if they do .rank? Because it keeps on doing undefined.

Comment: What did you try that keeps getting `undefined`?

Comment: Please show your code, I can't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

From [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) you can get the author of the message (the user). And with author you can get the User ID. So something like this should work:

```
var id = message.author.id;
```